# MYSQL Query Questions Search

Tags: mysql, record

Have been reading for a few days now and can't seem to get hold of my problem here.

Let me give you an insight of my DB:

table1 codes:

```
id   CODE
1    D0G08H13L12
2    D1G12H10L12
3    D0G10H12L11
4    D1G10H10L09
5    D0G08H13L12
6    D1G12H10L12
7    D0G08H13L12
8    D1G10H10L09
9    D0G08H13L12
10   D1G12H10L12
```

now I'm searching for a query to count which codes occurs the most after D0G08H13L12, so searching in the next record my answer from the query would be:

```
3 times  D1G12H10L12
1 time   D1G10H10L09
```

this is what I have until now, I think I have to use subquery but I'm not quite sure.

```
SELECT id, code, COUNT(code) FROM table1 WHERE id IN ($idprint +1) GROUP BY code 
ORDER BY COUNT(code) DESC
```

can any of you DB pro's help me in the good direction?

Comment: By "wich codes occurs the most after D0G08H13L12" do you mean that codes that have ID > 5?

Comment: This query will return all the codes and its count, do you want to exclude  D0G08H13L12 or you want to exclude the one with highest occurence

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, the idea is to find the code that occurs the most after occurence of D0G08H13L12 so ID doesnt matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) tot, `code`
FROM your_table
GROUP BY `code`
HAVING tot <= 
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM your_table
     WHERE code = 'D0G08H13L12')
    AND code <> 'D0G08H13L12'
ORDER BY tot DESC
```

If you want to have only two records append this to the query:

```
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY `code` HAVING tot < (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM

i get this error, im on version5.5.13 and using php myadmin 3.4.3.1

Comment: @user1000911: I've just tested it and it works! Did you change table names?

Comment: the query does work but it counts total of occurences in all of table, id like to count only the occurences in wich the previous record contains D0G08H13L12. 
in example:
id 1 D0G08H13L12
id 2 D1G12H10L12 
count 1 for D1G12H10L12
in example2:
id 3 D1G04H05L12
id 4 D1G12H10L12
count 0 for D1G12H10L12 because previous record did not contain D0G08H13L12

Comment: id like to calculate the relation between D0G08H13L12 and the following record, so i want to know wich codes occur the most by count directly in the next record after a record with code D0G08H13L12.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, This will give u the desired result....

```
    Select id, code, count(code) 
from table1 
where id>(select max(id) from table1 where code =D0G08H13L12) group by code order by count(code) desc;
```

Comment: Hi Sashi thank you, the query works i think, but not completely.
in my full DB i have 4600 occurences of D0G08H13L12 but it only counts a total of 17 with you query. if id sum up all the total counts it should count up to 4600.

Comment: hey, my query works on the rows present after the last occurance of D0G08H13L12, which i think was ur requirement..
If its clear then fine else please elaborate what u want

Comment: i think this query does it for only one occurence of D0G08H13L12 but id like it to check this for all of the occurences of D0G08H13L12 in the table.
i hope this helps, thx!

Comment: @user1000911: An example will explain...Please provide that

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(x.id), x.code
from yourTable x,
  (
  select * from yourTable
  where code = 'D0G08H13L12'
  ) v
where
  x.id > v.id
group by v.id
```

To get the most next codes for entered one.

Comment: i think this does the trick thanks! Can you also make it count? because now it just shows id's and output i think all records. But it does not count totals